# Rails conditional order by priority and status

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I want to order my `Order` model by priority, so that the ones with `priority: true` and with `status != 'delivered'` are on top. The ones with `priority: true` and `status: delivered` should be in the table below with all other orders sorted by updated_at.

In the end it should be sorted like this:

```
ID     PRIORITY     STATUS          UPDATED_AT
5      true         ready           1 min ago
8      true         in_transport    5 min ago

13     false        ready           less than a min ago
1      true         delivered       3 min ago         
2      false        delivered       15 min ago
4      true         delivered       16 min ago
10     false        in_transport    20 min ago
```

I managed to achieve this partially with:

```
orders = Order.where(...)
sql = "(CASE WHEN (priority = true AND status = 'delivered') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), priority desc"

orders.order(sql)
```

With this query the priority ones which are delivered are pushed to the end of the list and which I don't want:

```
ID     PRIORITY     STATUS          UPDATED_AT
5      true         ready           1 min ago
8      true         in_transport    5 min ago

13     false        ready           less than a min ago
2      false        delivered       15 min ago
10     false        in_transport    20 min ago 
...
1      true         delivered       3 min ago         
4      true         delivered       16 min ago
```

I would appriciate any guidelines here.

Comment: Why don't you formulate it as you said you wanted it: `CASE WHEN priority = true AND status != 'delivered' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, ...`?

Comment: I tried that as well, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

A possible approach is to use two separate queries and combine them.

Something like (not tested):

```
orders = Order.where(...)

priority_orders = orders.where(priority: true).where.not(status: 'delivered')
other_orders = orders.where.not(id: priority_orders.ids)

result = 
  priority_orders.order(updated_at: :desc) + 
  other_orders.order(priority: :desc, status: :asc, updated_at: :desc)
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be using multiple order clause.

```
sql = "(CASE WHEN (priority = true AND status = 'delivered') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), priority desc"
```

update the above to:

```
orders.order("CASE WHEN (priority = true AND status != 'delivered') THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, updated_at desc")
```

The query is self explanatory but let me know if you need any detail.